# Set output device for MediaElement or MediaPlayer

Tags: .net, media-player, mediaelement

MediaElement or MediaPlayer is sure a great way to play music within a .net application.
One thing I could not find out how to do is how to set the playback device. Is there a way to do it or does it always default to the standard audio device (since it comes from the web application).

Thanks in advance

Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always use the default sound device. I don't believe WPF supports a way to output to another device out of the box. For that, you will have to go a little lower level to DirectSound. Fortunately, there are a lot of great managed wrappers around DirectX, one I can recommend is [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the info! SlimDX seems to be powerfull, alas the documentation seems not to be as good as the code.

Answer (score 0):

Bass.net is a very powerful audio api which will let you do that and also set channels.  Unfortunately it is not free.  (no, I don't work for them)

You can also use the direct-x SDK to set sound device and integrate audio / video.

Comment: you sure that the link is correct? All I get is a site for, well, mainly fishing supply :-)

Comment: That is the name of the API, not the website,  I found that out too.. haha, website is: http://www.un4seen.com/

Comment: BTW, this was too expensive for my project,  I ended up just using direct-x sdk instead.   I believe there was another freeware api that was similar, but I just don't have it bookmarked anymore.